# Parsing HTML with HtmlAgilityPack in a htaccess-protected section of a website

Tags: c#, html, .htaccess, html-agility-pack

I am struggling to parse an html webpage in a htaccess-protected area of my website through a .aspx file in C# (the .aspx file is within the protected area). By debugging the code, I can get the raw page through the HtmlWeb().Load method, but when it comes to getting the html node (SelectSingleNode method), I get a null value.

Here is the sample code I am testing:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lbl.Text = getTextFromPage();
}

private string getTextFromPage()
{
    var web = new HtmlWeb();
    var doc = web.Load("html_address");
    HtmlNode node = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@id='reference_to_id']");

    if (node != null)
    {
        return node.InnerText;
    }
    else
    {
        return "nothing found";
    }
}
```

I always get a "nothing found" response, since the "node" object is null. If I remove the .htaccess file (thus removing the protection), everything works perfectly fine, so I suppose something should be done in the .htaccess definition. What shall I do?

EDIT:

I have included the content of the node in the question:

```
 <div id="reference_to_id"><p>test_test_test</p></div>
```

Comment: What's the contents of `doc` and `doc.DocumentNode`? It should provide some guidance on why your XPATH expression doesn't match anything.

Comment: The content of doc is a .html webpage, whereas the node contains a <p>some text</p> - the XPATH expression seems ok, since if I delete the .htacces file the above code works...

Comment: Does it include a `div` with the specified `id`?

Comment: yes, which is the one that you can see in the above code...

Comment: You should include the contents of `doc.DocumentNode` in the question.

Comment: Content included :)